# Place objects based on coordinates, not on the central coordinates in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector

[image]
I'm creating mesh objects dynamically based on the screen.

So objects that contain mesh objects are always the same size, but mesh objects have different shapes and sizes.

I want you to see my picture and understand it. In fact, blue area is transparent.

I am currently using a mobile camera to shoot Ray at the floor, and I want to place the object at the point where the Ray has hitted.

[image]
But this seems to require a lot of calculations.

I think we should use other coordinates than the object's central coordinates first.
And I think we should place the object a little bit above the collision point. Half the size of the mesh object,

So I tried this, but I failed. How can I solve this?

Below is my source code.

```
Vector3 hitPositon = hit.Pose.position;

Vector3 meshObjectCenter = ObjectPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;
Vector3 meshObjectSize = ObjectPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;

Vector3 CenterPointRevision = meshObjectCenter - hitPositon;
Vector3 YAxisRevision = new Vector3(0, meshObjectSize.y / 2, 0);
           
Vector3 NewPoint = ARObjectPrefab.transform.position - CenterPointRevision + YAxisRevision;
           
ObjectPrefab.transform.position = NewPoint;
```

[image]

Object is in this format, and the picture above looks successful but fail case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position is just the hit location minus the offset to center plus the y-axis offset:

```
Vector3 hitPositon = hit.Pose.position;
Vector3 meshObjectCenter = ObjectPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;
Vector3 meshObjectSize = ObjectPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;
Vector3 YAxisRevision = new Vector3(0, meshObjectSize.y / 2, 0);
ObjectPrefab.transform.position = hitPositon - meshObjectCenter + YAxisRevision;
```

Comment: I've already done it. It's a problem that occurred because the center of the object wasn't at the center of the mesh, like the picture of the question. So I have to calculate that.

Comment: Your mesh isn't centered at 0,0,0? What is the parent of the mesh?

Comment: There is no parent object.
I want you to think that my object is 1080 x 2220 size, And any coordinates value(rendering center) should move to the hit position.

Comment: See the update. I don't know what `ARObjectPrefab` is in your original code, but I don't think it is necessary. I think you just got the order of operations wrong. With vectors addition is commutative (a + b = b + a) but subtraction is not (a - b ≠ b - a)